# Requesting assistance with a keyboard related thing

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have bought this Cherry MY-7000 model keyboard, it is bit older and bought from a second-hand electronics store for a low price. It has the swipe card reader thing, and the thing I would want to do is that when I swipe a specific card through it, it would do cool functions that can be chosen by me. I tried the Cherry Designer driver software that is available from the site of this keyboard, but it only allows few Windows commands, like "Mute" and "Play/Pause". I am running Windows 7. Thank you.

Comment: Is it a PS2 based keyboard [like this one](http://www.amazon.com/Cherry-MY-7000-104-key-Keyboard-Swipe/dp/B007V6YKV6) or is it an USB based one? Can you link to the precise model?

Comment: It is PS/2 and the model is G81-7000

Comment: Most PS/2 based barcode scanners and card readers worked by presenting a scan/card_read by just outputting a number of characters. What happens if you open notepad and swipe a card?

Comment: It types out bunch of numbers, like the number of the card and some numbers that I cant figure out what they represent.

Comment: So yeah, it basically inputs the info of the card as text.

Comment: In that case no driver is needed. It is already working. If you have a field where they ask you for your insurance number, your password (or whatever is on the card) you get the chance to either type it, or to swipe the card.

Answer (score 0):

The [Cherry website](http://www.cherrycorp.com/english/keyboards/pos/7000/) has a [keyboard datasheet](http://www.cherrycorp.com/english/keyboards/pdf/G81_7000.pdf) with the following information:

- You either have the G81-7000LPAUS-0 (light gray/beige) or the G81-7000LPAUS-2 (black, as shown below).
- The  magnetic card reader keyboards G81-7000 offer the functions of a keyboard and magnetic card reader in one single data entry system. These keyboards are ideal for
  recording all data via magnetic cards and barcodes - such as in the hotel and catering business, the travel industry or in banks and insurance companies.  (aka simple entry of numbers in a prearranged format).

It does not explicitly mention the data read from the swipe cards, however for the optional barcode reader it mentions this: **Data is converted to "scan codes" and transmitted via the PS/2 interface (like normal key operations).**

(This was normal in the time of PS/2 barcode reader and scanners.)

This means that you do not need any additional software to read swipe cards or bar codes. The input will be indistinguishable from normal key presses.

[image: Picture of a Cherry multiboard G81-7000]
Cherry multiboard G81-7000

Note that the USB version seems to have more features. E.g. "Parsing and Configuration of the Magnetic Stripe Data Stream".

Comment: hmm, you could possibly write something using AHK to make sense of it and do some action